# Able to bypass login by typing the secure route directly into the address bar

Tags: authentication, passport.js, express-session

Working on passport local strategy project. Everything functioning well except if login fails (e.g. due to incorrect password) I'm able to reach the protected page by typing the protected route in the address bar. Without prior login failure it functions as it supposed to. Dependencies installed: express, express-session, mongoose, passport, passport-local. Here is the app.js:

```
'use strict';
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const ejs = require('ejs');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('home'));
app.get('/login', (req, res) => res.render('login'));
app.get('/register', (req, res) => res.render('register'));

const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

const passport = require('passport');
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    return cb(null, {
      id: user.id,
      username: user.username,
      picture: user.picture
    });
  });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, cb) {
process.nextTick(function() {
  return cb(null, user);
});
});

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_STRING).then(
  console.log('got the db')
).catch(
  err => console.error(err)
  );

const User = require('./User');

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

app.get('/restricted', async (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    try {
      const foundUsers = await User.find({'secrets': {$ne: []}});
      res.render('restricted', {usersWithSecrets: foundUsers});
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});


app.get('/submit', (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render('submit');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});

app.post('/logout', function(req, res, next){
  req.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  req.login(user, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate('local') (req, res, function() {
        res.redirect('/restricted');
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/register');
    } else {
      passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res, function() {
        res.redirect('/restricted');
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post('/submit', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user.id}, {$push: {'secrets': req.body.secretToPost}});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

app.post('/submit', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user.id}, {$push: {'secrets': req.body.secretToPost}});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, console.log('app is up'));
```

Comment: you need to add the auth middleware so that it checks if the user is allowed to access the route without logged in

Comment: Could you show an example? I believe that if(req.isAuthenticated){}else{} inside my app.get('/restricted') route is the auth middleware you're mentioning. I cannot access the restricted page by typing it directly into the address bar without logging in. But if the login attempt fails, suddenly I can.